# Not able to insert Value using SparkSql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to insert some values in my hive table using sparksql.I'm using below code.

```
    val filepath:String = "/user/usename/filename.csv'"
    val fileName : String = filepath
    val result = fileName.split("/") 
    val fn=result(3)  //filename
    val e=LocalDateTime.now() //timestamp
```

First I tried using Insert Into Values but then i found this feature is not available in sparksql.

```
    val ds=sparksession.sql("insert into mytable("filepath,filename,Start_Time")  values('${filepath}','${fn}','${e}')
```

is there any other way to insert these values using sparksql(mytable is empty,I need to load this table everyday)?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use Spark Dataframe Write API to insert data into the table.
If you do not have the Spark Dataframe then first create one Dataframe using spark.createDataFrame() then, try as follow to write the data:

`df.write.insertInto("name of hive table")`

Answer (score -1):

Hi Below code worked for me since i need to use variable in my dataframe so first i created dataframe form selected data then using df.write.insertInto(tablename) saved in hive table.

```
    val filepath:String = "/user/usename/filename.csv'"
    val fileName : String = filepath
    val result = fileName.split("/") 
    val fn=result(3)  //filename
    val e=LocalDateTime.now() //timestamp
    val df1=sparksession.sql(s" select '${filepath}' as file_path,'${fn}' as filename,'${e}' as Start_Time")
    df1.write.insertInto("dbname.tablename")
```